# Blender-based Rendering Webapp

Tags: blend4web

Is it possible to run blender server-side, with a premade .blend file? I would like to create a web app that (using blender) renders different images, with a user-selected texture. Could anyone point me in the right direction?
I've seen https://www.blend4web.com/ but I don't think it has the option to use a pre-made blend file with a custom texture. (If it does, could someone link a tutorial?)

Comment: If the server can run Blender, then this is possible. Blender runs on various Linux, Windows and Mac Distros. Blend4Web does not run Blender, but simply shows exported data in webgl. You will want a serversided language that calls Blender in background mode from the command line.

Comment: Do you know of a easy way/an PHP wrapper for blender? @Leander

Comment: Just call standard [command line rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html#command-line-rendering) with [php](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php).